# Javascript AJAX API generation for Django

Tags: javascript, django, web-applications

I have a Django page that uses AJAX in some places to enhance the page. Currently the backend for these AJAX calls are normal Django views that return JSON and the URLs to these views are hardcoded in Django.

I'm currently looking for different, nicer way to solve this. My idea is the following: Have some "magic" that takes Python code within Django and exposes a API for it. Additionally, a JS file is generated that can be included into the page that exposes this API to Javascript. Ideally all underlying work is hidden. Is there a project that does this? Or are there alternative ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many modules designed for API-building, but I don't think any of those (Django REST Framework, Piston, Tastypie) fits your needs.
What maybe is something that is similar to your description is the [Dajax Project](http://www.dajaxproject.com/) - it has some automatic ajax registration stuff.